# How can I correctly display utf-8 encoded characters in a MessageBox in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, utf-8, character-encoding, c++20

I used **mppoker/cpp-httplib**

```
bool Request::Login()
{
    std::string json = "{ \"email\": \"" + std::string(User::GetUsername()) + "\", \"password\": \"" + std::string(User::GetPassword()) + "\" }";
    auto res = client->Post("/api/client/auth/login", json, "application/json");
    if (res && res->status == 200) {
        auto j = nlohmann::json::parse(res->body);
        // perty print
        int indent = 4;
        std::string s = j.dump(indent);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        auto j = nlohmann::json::parse(res->body);
        std::string err = j["error"];
        MessageBox(NULL, err.c_str(), "Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Example API Response

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "`Email sai định dạng`"
  "path": "/api/client/auth/login",
  "method": "POST"
}
```

[image: MessageBox]

The code I provided is returning an error message from an API in json format, but when trying to display the error message in a MessageBox, the utf-8 characters are not being displayed correctly. What can I do to properly display utf-8 encoded characters in a MessageBox in C++?

Comment: Convert to a wide string and use `MessageBoxW`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar

Comment: Is your UTF-8 invalid or not? You seem to be asking two different questions. Stripping invalid UTF-8 is not the same as displaying valid UTF-8.

Comment: Alternatively, you can [use UTF-8 code pages in Windows apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page) (starting with Windows 10 1903).